# The subscription being used exceeds the cpu cores quota

Tags: azure, azure-hdinsight

I keep on getting the above message when I am trying to set up a new HDInsight HBase cluster.

However I am only trying to use 1 core in the new cluster and according to the Azure portal (when I go to Settings-Usage (see screenshot below) I am using 0% of 40 cores.

Does anybody know how to resolve this?

[image: Screenshot of Azure Portal]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HDInsight core limits are calculated separately from the cores that are shown in the Settings-Usage tab.  If you click on one of your existing HDInsight clusters, you should see a graphic that outlines the cores used by that cluster, as well as the total cores used and the overall limit, similar to:

[image: Usage Screenshot]

Alternately you can use Azure Powershell's [Get-AzureHDInsightProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn593747.aspx) cmdlet to list the cores used/available in your subscription.

Keep in mind that the number of cores uses is based on the CPU cores of all of the VMs included in the cluster.  For example, a 2 data node cluster will actually use 16 cores (Two A3 Head Nodes with 4 cores each and two A3 Data Nodes with 4 cores each).  The VM sizes can vary depending on configuration options and cluster type. Details on the VM sizes included in a cluster can be seen at: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/hdinsight/

If you need additional cores allocated for your subscription, open a case with Support Type=**Billing** at https://manage.windowsazure.com/?getsupport=true and then select *"Quota or Core Increase Requests"* as the problem type, and *"HDInsight"* as the category.

Comment: This is probably the answer and I raised the support ticket as suggested. Microsoft support are still "working" on it however even though I have made them aware of this answer.

Comment: This took a while to fix. Anyone following this when you raise the Billing support request with Microsoft be very specific about requiring additional HDInsight cores. Microsoft initially gave me additional normal cores (ie the ones you see at Settings-Usage).