# ADF activities and Ondemand HDInsight instances

Tags: azure-hdinsight, azure-data-factory, ondemand

I am new to using on demand hd insight. I have a basic question -

I have multiple activities running **simultaneously** in separate ADF pipelines each using an HDInsight ondemand linked service. How many instances of HDInsight gets created? Is it one instance per activity?

I got confused a bit because the documentation states that each instance created has a time-to-live value within which if a new job comes it will process that. Does the new job need to come from an activity in the same pipeline that originally created the instance or this instance is shared across activities in other pipelines?

Also just wanted to confirm my understanding that the cores count used for on demand instances do not count towards the subscription usage count.

Really sorry if the questions are very basic but any help very much appreciated.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question. But wonder if you've considered using Data Lake Analytics instead of HDInsight? The USQL jobs are much easier to control and much more costs affective.

Comment: Yes @paulandrew, we considered that but client is more inclined to hadoop due to maturity level and believe USQL might lead to certain restrictions in transformational abilities. Please correct me if this understanding is invalid. Also  trying to understand the pricing for the usage of compute engines in ADF - for USQL we are providing degreeofparallelism in ADF json, The help document mentions this to be Big Analytics Unit. Is that the same as AU on which USQL jobs are billed?

Comment: The partial answer is hidden in [url](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-compute-linked-services)  "If the timetolive property value is appropriately set, multiple pipelines can share the instance of the on-demand HDInsight cluster." But still not clear if multiple pipelines simultaneously fired will create cluster only for pipeline that hits deck first? I feel there could be chance more than one cluster get created if more than one pipelines hit together. Is there any guidance to estimate the number of ondemand clusters created as that impacts cost and CPU limit?

Answer (score 0):

Partial answers to my questions provided below - refer to comments section above for open points.

Answer for sharing of instance across pipelines is available at [url](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-compute-linked-services) -> "If the timetolive property value is appropriately set, multiple pipelines can share the instance of the on-demand HDInsight cluster."

Regarding my other question on CPU limits for HDInsight, as per [azure limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits) -> the ondemand HDinsight core limits are restricted to 60 per subscription and this is different than the general core limit per subscription.

Also interestingly for manually created HDInsight clusters there exists a CPU limit as mentioned in [this Stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27944760/the-subscription-being-used-exceeds-the-cpu-cores-quota). It is as of today 170 per subscription obtainable by issuing the powershell command Get-AzureHDInsightProperties. Again I understand this limit is different than the subscription general core limit.